# How can I refactor to avoid repetition finding the index of strings in a list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of strings where I want to find the index of a first- and second-choice video compressor.

Logic: If the first choice is available, return its index. If not, and the second choice is available, return its index. If not, return zero.

Here is what I have now:

```
List<string> availableVideoCompressors = GetAvailableVideoCompressors();
int compressorIndexToUse = 0;
if (availableVideoCompressors.Any(c => c.StartsWith("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    compressorIndexToUse = availableVideoCompressors.Select((c, i) => new { c, i }).First(c => c.c.Equals("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).i;
else if (availableVideoCompressors.Any(c => c.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    compressorIndexToUse = availableVideoCompressors.Select((c, i) => new {c, i}).First(c => c.c.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).i;
return compressorIndexToUse;
```

The problem is that I am iterating the list several times. Once to determine if the desired compressor is available, then again to obtain its index, for each candidate compressor.

I am not sure how to refactor to avoid this repetition. What can I do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have the list of compressors, I would do the following:

```
var index = availableVideoCompressors.FindIndex(c => c.StartsWith("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (index == -1)
    index = availableVideoCompressors.FindIndex(c => c.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (index == -1)
    return 0;
return index;
```

Comment: This is effectively what I went with because I feel it was the clearest to read, but also only iterated the list (at most) once for each choice.

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with a simpler problem where there's just one choice:

```
for (var i = 0; i < compressors.Count; i++)
{
    if (compressors[i].StartsWith(firstChoice, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return i;
    }
}

return 0;
```

(I would much prefer returning -1 if no match is found, but requirements are requirements.)

Now we can build on top of this to deal with the second preference:

```
var secondChoiceIndex = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < compressors.Count; i++)
{
    if (compressors[i].StartsWith(firstChoice, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        return i;
    }

    if (secondChoiceIndex == -1 && compressors[i].StartsWith(secondChoice, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        secondChoiceIndex = i;
    }
}

return secondChoiceIndex == -1 ? 0 : secondChoiceIndex;
```

Comment: You could make secondChoice an `int?` loaded with null at start, and then at the end `return secondChoice ?? 0`.

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce it to only up to two iterations by changing `.First()` to `.FirstOrDefault()` and removing the ifs.

```
private static int GetDesiredIndex(List<string> availableVideoCompressors)
{
    var namesWithIndexes = availableVideoCompressors
        .Select((compressor, index) => new { Name = compressor, Index = index })
        .ToList();
    var ffdshow = namesWithIndexes
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.Equals("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (ffdshow != null)
        return ffdshow.Index;
    var msVideo1 = namesWithIndexes
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (msVideo1 != null)
    {
        return msVideo1.Index;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your logic goes a little beyond a simple search you have to write your own method in order to avoid multiple enumerations. Unless your list is huge (10K+ elements), or you're regenerating your list every enumeration, it probably won't make much performance difference.

```
int FindWithFallback(IEnumerable<string> enumerable, string primary, string secondary)
{
    bool foundPrimary = false;
    bool foundSecondary = false;
    int primaryIndex = -1;
    int secondaryIndex = 0;
    foreach(var c in enumerable) 
    {
        ++primaryIndex;
        if (c.StartsWith(primary, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            foundPrimary = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (!foundSecondary && c.StartsWith(secondary, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            foundSecondary = true;
            secondaryIndex = primaryIndex;
        }
    }

    if (foundPrimary) 
    {
        return primaryIndex;
    }
    else if (foundSecondary) 
    {
        return secondaryIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Now I'm getting ridiculous, but since this was tagged Linq:

```
private int choiceVideoCompressor(List<string> l)
{
    return l.IndexOf(
           l.Where(c => c.StartsWith("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           .Concat(l.Where(c => c.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
           .Concat(l).First());
}
```

This only iterate over the list until one element is found. Thus if the list contains `"ffdshow"`, it will only loops once!

That is some nice lazy evaluation :)

I did have to cheat and get the index of the element with `IndexOf()`, meaning the list is iterated one time extra up until the element is found again.

You can get around that with this trick:

```
private int choiceVideoCompressor2(List<string> l)
{
   var l1 = l.Select((element, index) => new { e = element, i = index });
   return l1.Where(c => c.e.StartsWith("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .Concat(l1.Where(c =>c.e.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            .Concat(l1)
            .First().i;
}
```

This also does not actually loops over the code more than needed. Even `l1` is only evaluated up to the first element if the list start with `"ffdshow"`.

Edit: Improved version based on comments:

```
    private int choiceVideoCompressor(IEnumerable<string> l, IEnumerable<string> fallbacks)
    {
        var l1 = l.Select((element, index) =>  new { e = element, i = index });
        var l2 = l1.Take(0);
        foreach (string s in fallbacks)) {
            l2 = l2.Concat(l1.Where(c => c.e.StartsWith(s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
        }
        return l2.Concat( new[] {new { e = "", i = 0 }}).First().i;
    }
```

This handels N fallbacks and wont throw a InvalidOperationException when the list is empty.

Comment: This is very clever. I like how you get around the ordering issue by using consecutive concats. The only problem with your solution is that it fails on an empty source, but that's pretty easy to fix. Also, your method could take an IEnumerable instead of List. Thumbs Up for a really good idea. Do you think it could be possible to extend this to n fallback values instead of keeping it to 2?

Comment: A empty list completely slipped my mind. I'm not even sure how to handle that: You could return 0 here but down the road somewhere you will need to select a decoder before you can display a video. Then again, a InvalidOperationException is probably not expected here no. As for n fall-backs: I'll edit you a nice one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Find` method with custom search delegate inside:

```
string compressor = availableVideoCompressors.Find(delegate(string rec){ 
    return (rec.StartsWith("ffdshow") || rec.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1"));
});

return compressor;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx

**UPDATE:** I missed a requirement that first choice match should have priority over the other. It has been answered in other answers already, but for the sake of correctness of the code, here is the updated version:

```
int index = availableVideoCompressors.FindIndex(delegate(string rec){ 
    return (rec.StartsWith("ffdshow"));
});

if (index < 0) {
    index = availableVideoCompressors.FindIndex(delegate(string rec){ 
        return rec.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1");
});

return index;
```

Comment: This returns a string when I actually need the *index*, but I think this may be the right direction.

Comment: There is similar `FindIndex` method if you do need an index. I thought you only need an index to get an actual string.

Comment: If the second preference appears before the first in `availableVideoCompressors`, this code will return the second preference.

Comment: @mjolka: Good catch! Thank you. I didn't realize this requirement.

Comment: Isn't this a more elaborate way of writing `return availableVideoCompressors.Find(x => x.StartsWith("ffdshow") || x.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1"));`?

Comment: @sha: if you know that your refactored code is buggy as per the spec, **why** don't you correct it??

Comment: @Aneves: buggy - no, not according to specs - yes :) updated. There were few correct answers already and I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: You can do `int index = availableVideoCompressors.FindIndex(rec => rec.StartWith("ffdshow"));`.

Comment: (Also, note that for `["foo", "bar"]`, the expected result is 0 but the actual result is -1.)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you are trying to accomplish can easily be done through the use of the Aggregate method but I would stay away from it for performance reasons. You cannot early return from an Aggregate process so you would have to continue looping for all items in the list even though you found a valid result.

I would instead use a variant of the TakeWhile method to scan through the list until the interesting element is found. The issue with TakeWhile is that it tests for the predicate before returning the value. This causes the returned index to always be one iteration off. This is where the TakeUntil method comes into play. Basically, where TakeWhile acts like a while loop, TakeUntil acts like a do while loop.

This method tracks two values, the final index to return and a score of the best value found so far.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeUntil<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}

public static int FindIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] firstOf) {
    var bestScore = Int32.MaxValue;
    var foundIndex = 0;

    return source.Select((v, i) =>
    {
        var currentScore = Array.IndexOf(firstOf, v);

        // Found a match so update the score and save the current index;
        if (currentScore != -1 && currentScore < bestScore)
        {
            bestScore = currentScore;
            foundIndex = i;
        }

        return foundIndex;
    })
    // Found the best possible match so return early.
    .TakeUntil(_ => bestScore == 0)
    .Last();
}
```

Comment: Also, as a bonus, my solution supports an unlimited amount of fallbacks. The closer to the beginning of the list, the better they are. It could be multi threaded easily through the use of concurrent bags. If you need to customize how elements are compared, you can implement IEquatable on T. And it comes as a handy extension method.

Comment: Extreme overkill. But interesting to read, regardless.

Comment: I fail to see how it is overkill. It is, with your solution, the only solutions that uses linq in their answer which I considered a requirement according to question's tags. It is also the only solution that does it in a single pass which was, in a way, a requirement too.

Comment: I find it overkill because it seems more complex and convoluted than it needs to be. For example, I am not sure whether it will select (1,2,3) or (3,3,3), and I am not sure that it works without running it. The solution being so much more complicated than the requirement indicates, to me, that it can be improved. It's just an opinion.

Comment: After a little bit of testing, I updated the whole thing. Unfortunately, it requires a custom extension method to work, which is sad, but it is at least reusuable. It also feels a lot less convulated now. As for what it select, it is actually neither. It always select the best possible match so far, so it would be (0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 5) with values of (5, 4, 2).

Answer (score 2):

Well, just store the found index in a variabel. FindIndex is your friend here, but it returns -1 when no match is found. This is preferred normally so you can see the difference between a match on the first element and no match.

```
    private int choiceVideoCompressor(List<string> l)
    {
        int index = l.FindIndex(c => c.StartsWith("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        return index != -1 ? index :l.FindIndex(c => c.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
   }
```

And, when you want to return 0 instead of -1 when no default is found:

```
    private int choiceVideoCompressor(List<string> l)
    {
        int index = l.FindIndex(c => c.StartsWith("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        index = index != -1 ? index : l.FindIndex(c => c.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        return index != -1 ? index : 0;
    }
```

You can call this function with

```
    choiceVideoCompressor(GetAvailableVideoCompressors());
```

Comment: I would prefer to remove the ternary and use `if(index >= 0) { return index; } return list.FindIndex(...);`. IMO simpler is better.

Comment: Yeah you can always replace the ternary if you absolutely want to avoid it. You can also use `return Math.max(index, 0)` on the last line if you think that's more clear. Still, i deemed this case simple enough to allow a ternary over adding 4 lines for a if statement and multiple exit points.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas. The first assumes you have no control over the order of `availableVideoCompressors` and the second assumes you do.

You could store the video compressors you want in the order you want them in a separate `List`. Adding one to the list is a simple matter of adding one to the `prefs` variable.

```
List<string> availableVideoCompressors = new List<string>() { "a", "b" };
List<string> prefs = new List<string>() { "b", "a" };
int index = -1;

foreach (string x in prefs)
{
    index = availableVideoCompressors.FindIndex(x);

    if (index > -1)
        return index;
}

return 0;
```

If you have control over the creation of the `availableVideoCompressors` then you could add items to the list in the order you would want them, and then the code below would follow the original spec:

```
var index = availableVideoCompressors
    .FindIndex(c => c.StartsWith("ffdshow", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 || c.StartsWith("Microsoft Video 1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

return index == -1
    ? 0
    : index;
```

Comment: This might return "Microsoft Video 1" index while "ffdshow" is listed lower, but it should only give the the second option if the first one is unavailable as per spec.

Comment: @Dorus: That's exactly how this will work, hence the `||` operator.

Comment: Logic: If the first choice is available, return its index. **If not**, and the second choice is available, return its index. If not, return zero.

Comment: And that's exactly how this code works. The ternary expression in the return statement checks for a -1 and returns 0.

Comment: If the list contains { "Microsoft Video 1", "ffdshow" }, it will return "Microsoft Video 1", but it should be returning "ffdshow".

Comment: -1: refactored code does not follow the spec of the original code, as pointed out by @Dorus .

Comment: I see what the OP is after now. Didn't have time to change my answer. Let me work in it.

Comment: I changed my answer so it implements the OP's original spec. Sorry for the confusion.